# The type arguments for method MyFunction<T>(Func<T>) cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#

I am trying out this piece of code below from:
[Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)
But, it gives error:
The type arguments for method TimeoutFileAction(Func) cannot be inferred from the usage.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
TimeoutFileAction(() => { System.IO.File.etc...; return null; } );
Reusable method that times out after 2 seconds

private T TimeoutFileAction<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    var started = DateTime.UtcNow;
    while ((DateTime.UtcNow - started).TotalMilliseconds < 2000)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();                    
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException exception)
        {
            //ignore, or log somewhere if you want to
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Could you figure out type based on just ‘null’? How do you expect compiler to sort it out?

Comment: Because your are returning null, the function is unable to infer the return type for T. If you know the return type you can return using a cast e.g. `return (object)null;`

Comment: Did you mean to use `Action<T>` instead which does not return a value? Why return `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MUST have an output other than Type of `void`.

When you do this: `() => { System.IO.File.etc...; return null; }` the output type is `void` and you cannot have that for a `Func<T>`. If you want a Void Type then use `Action`.

If you want both `void` and `T`, then just write an overflow method. Se Code below:

```
   public static void Main()
    {
        var today = new DateTime(2021, 10, 25, 5, 40, 0);

        Console.WriteLine(today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(36));

        TimeoutFileAction(() => { Test(); });
        TimeoutFileAction(Test);
    }

    private static string Test() => "Test";

    private static void TimeoutFileAction(Action func)
    {
        var started = DateTime.UtcNow;
        while ((DateTime.UtcNow - started).TotalMilliseconds < 2000)
        {
            try
            {
                func();
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                //ignore, or log somewhere if you want to
            }
        }
    }

    private static T TimeoutFileAction<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        var started = DateTime.UtcNow;
        while ((DateTime.UtcNow - started).TotalMilliseconds < 2000)
        {
            try
            {
                return func();
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                //ignore, or log somewhere if you want to
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```